# Protractor gives "Unable to start a WebDriver session" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I already have started a server with `webdriver-manager start`, but I get this error when I try to run protractor:

```
Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

C:\...\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
```

My config file looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
    specs: [
        'test/*.js'
    ],

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'

};
```

I have also tried pointing to the binary in the capabilities object as well as adding chromeDriver and seleniumServerJar keys to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [relevant github issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/950), the problem is that **`chromedriver` cannot find `chrome` browser executeable** - on different operating systems it searches for it in [different places](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Requirements).

You need to either have *chrome installed* where `chromedriver` expects it to be, or specify the path to the `chrome` executeable in the `binary` setting:

```
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": {
        binary: "D:/Program Files/Chrome/chrome.exe",
        args: [],
        extensions: [],
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to put "binary" a level down inside "capabilities" ... didn't know it should have been in "chromeOptions"

Answer (score 0):

I generated code using JHipster and had similar error where e2e was not working. I provided binary path. But upon `npm run e2e` the browser opened and displayed `data;` in the address bar.

I shuffled and provided the binary at the end of chromeOptions after the args and it worked.

```
capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: process.env.JHI_E2E_HEADLESS
                ? [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
                : [ "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ],
            binary: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
        }
    }
```

Note: I also had to update the chrome version when an unsupported webdriver version error occurred.