# protractor "ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session"

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have some it tests on my single-page-app written in angular.
the tests are in protractor.

they ran during the build before, but now that I moved all of them to a branch something got broken and when I run the tests I'm getting:

```
Running "protractor:normal" (protractor) task
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://172.31.9.226:23730/wd/hub
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

c:\projects\blog-manager\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-    webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
var template = new Error(this.message);
             ^
Warning: Protractor test(s) failed. Exit code: 1 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 6
```

the conf file is as follows:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

    specs: [
            process.cwd() + '/test/spec/e2e/**/*.js'//,
           // process.cwd() + '/test/e2e/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    framework: 'jasmine',

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        "chromeOptions": {
            binary: "C:/Program Files      (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
            args: [],
           extensions: [],
        }
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        // Disable animations so e2e tests run more quickly
        var disableNgAnimate = function () {
            angular.module('disableNgAnimate', []).run(function ($animate) {
                $animate.enabled(false);
            });
        };

        browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);

        // Store the name of the browser that's currently being used.
        browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
            browser.params.browser = caps.get('browserName');
        });
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000
    }
};
```

any suggestions on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: @Saifur I am running them using web-storm configuration which is the equivalent of running them locally through command-line. the grunt serve command passes successfully prior to testing

Answer (score 1):

According to alecxe's answer it's chrome binary issue which can be solved by installing chrome in same place as `chromedriver` expects to be or specifying the executable path to the binary settings.

```
capabilities: {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions": {
        binary: "D:/Program Files/Chrome/chrome.exe",
        args: [],
        extensions: [],
    }
},
```

See his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493715/protractor-gives-unable-to-start-a-webdriver-session-error)

Even though you are setting the executable path correctly it seems little off to me binary: `"C:/Program Files      (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",`

Is this correct?

Alternatively, I would try [this](https://letmedothat.wordpress.com/category/protractor-2/)